# Constraints break while scrolling when runtime hiding UIViews in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

The problem statement is - Constraint breaks while scrolling between cells where I'm hiding/showing `UIImageView` based on the logic, the picture is available or not. One more thing I want to point out here is I'm changing the height of `UIImageView` runtime based on the Picture size (Landscape, square or portrait).

[image]

Code kept inside custom `UITableViewCell`

```
// Image --
guard let photoUrl = URL(string: homeFeedModel.videoThumbnail) else {
   self.imageviewNewsFeed.image = nil
   self.imageviewNewsFeed.isHidden = true
   return
}
self.imageviewNewsFeed.isHidden = false 

// Picture height calculation
let widthOfScreen = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
let heightOfScreen = Double(widthOfScreen) * homeFeedModel.videoFrameHeight / homeFeedModel.videoFrameWidth
let heightToSetForImagePlayer = CGFloat(heightOfScreen)
self.heightConstraintImageViewNewsFeed.constant = heightToSetForImagePlayer
```

`UIImageView` has been kept inside `Stackview`, which is automatically managing to resize of a cell if UIView is there or not.

[image]

Any other better way to implement this use case?

Comment: change priority of height constraint to 750

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Hi Prashant. Thanks for the suggestion. Let me try it out.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Hey Prashant, It worked. Thanks. But what I actually don't understand is how it relates to priority, I would really appreciate it if you can help me to figure out your logic?

Comment: It is always a good practice to have constraint with low priority  specially with UItableview and collectionview, Because while calculating something while scrolling there is a case where you got some fraction value like **179.998**  But you have **180**